# Unable to take browser full page screenshot

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

Here my code
code 1:

```
scenario.embed(sharedDriver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES), "image/png");
```

code 2:

```
 BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            File file = new File("image.png");
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
            scenario.embed(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file), "image/png");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

code 3:

```
  try {

            Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(new ViewportPastingStrategy(2000)).takeScreenshot(sharedDriver);
            File file = new File("screenshot.png");
            ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(), "png", file);
            scenario.embed(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file), "image/png");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But none of the above code take full page screenshot. It just take only visible browser screen.
I'm running test it in linux machine. I didn't test in windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what browser you are using but the screen capturing behavior works differently for different browsers. Only Firefox is capable of taking a full screenshot without helper tools like AShot. So your "code1" block might only work for Firefox.

Your "code2" block will not work as Java Robot library works only with physical screen contents so if there is anything that does not appear on the screen, it won't be visible.

AShot however should work fine for any browser (at least for Chrome and Firefox). I think you just have an issue with your code. Try changing your code like this:

```
Screenshot screenCapture = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
```

Comment: Thanks, actually the code works fine, but it doesn't work for my application. And i don't know why. Is there any key to identify the problem?

Comment: I have found that my application has some footer with company name, is that an issue for scrolling and capturing?

Comment: @DINESHKUMAR This shouldn't cause any issue as long as this footer or whatever is in the viewport. So the rest of your page is captured and this is the only area that is excluded?

Comment: It is freezed footer. It is displayed in normal viewscreen. If i scroll using mouse, the footer doesn't move, only the content will move. I execute the code it works good in other web applications. But it doesn't work in our application.

Comment: So, image captured with footer, rest of the page is not captured in both chrome and firefox.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code . It works for me atleast.

```
// Get the entire page screenshot
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        BufferedImage fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
```

Comment: This might only work for Firefox. Not all browsers are capable of capturing full page screenshots out of the box.

Comment: Possible. But we can try atleast